# Macro-defining macro in Racket?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, racket, hygiene

In Common Lisp it is relatively easy to create a macro-defining macro. For example, the following macro

```
(defmacro abbrev (short long)
  `(defmacro ,short (&rest args)
     `(,',long ,@args)))
```

is a macro-defining macro, because it expands to another macro.

If we now put

```
(abbrev def defun)
```

in our program, we can write `def` instead of `defun` whenever we define a new function.
Of course, `abbrev` can be used for other things, too. For example, after

```
(abbrev /. lambda)
```

we can write `(/. (x) (+ x 1))` instead of `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`. Nice. (For detailed explanation of abbrev, see http://dunsmor.com/lisp/onlisp/onlisp_20.html)

Now, my questions are:

1. Can I write the macro-defining macros in Racket?
2. If I can, how to do that? (for example, how to write something similar to
   `abbrev` macro in Racket?)

Comment: You inverted your macro parameters, long should come first.

Comment: I corrected that in my question. Tanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html#%28part._.Macro-.Generating_.Macros%29) part of the Racket Guide:

```
(define-syntax-rule (abbrev short long)
  (define-syntax-rule (short body (... ...))
    (long body (... ...))))
```

Quoting the above link:

> The only non-obvious part of its definition is the (... ...), which
>   “quotes” ... so that it takes its usual role in the generated macro,
>   instead of the generating macro.

Now

```
(abbrev def define)
(abbrev /. lambda) 
(def f (/. (x) (+ x 1)))
(f 3)
```

yields

```
4
```

FWIW, it works on Guile as well, so it's no Racket-specific thing.

Answer (score 5):

ad 1. Yes.
ad 2. Your example can most easily be written

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (abbrev stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ short long)
     #'(define-syntax short (make-rename-transformer #'long))]))

(abbrev def define)
(def x 42)
x
```

The example above evaluates to 42.

Comment: The 'new' term is creating confusion here ('short' is actually new term). It will be clearer if 'long' is used (instead of 'new') as in other places on this page.

Comment: I agree. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I find that renaming can be done simply with define or let statements:

```
(define =? =)
(define lr list-ref)
```

or:

```
(let ((=? =)
      (lr list-ref))
  (println (lr '(1 2 3) 2))
  (println (=? 1 2))
  (println (=? 1 1)))
```

Output:

```
3
#f
#t
```

There seem to be no need for any macro for this purpose.

Comment: That doesn't work when you want to rename a special form or a macro like `define` or `lambda`

Comment: What works then is `(define-syntax def (make-rename-transformer #'define))` or `(define-syntax /. (make-rename-transformer #'lambda))`